# Eclipse Creating a New Project

Tags: java, eclipse

Is it possible to create a new java project in eclipse with a default class and main method without having to manually create a class in the src folder? I start eclipse.exe. File->New->Java Project->New -> Class->New -> Class->Created a class What I am looking for is New->Java Project->Created project.  In this case, I want a project that includes a class file and a main method by default.

Comment: It's not possible in one step.  You're leaving out the step where after you create the Java project, you create a package for the src file, then you create the class.

Comment: You could use Gradle to create a project skeleton for you: `gradle init --type java-application`. Keep in mind that there is not necessarily only one `main` function in the project; many classes could have a `main`, e.g., for utilities. The jar or war file would still define the main `main` (pun intended).

Comment: Yes, Gradle will generate the required skeleton, but it may be an overkill for my needs. @Robert.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, I skipped the package creation step because Eclipse automatically places new classes in the default package when I create them. I found a workaround by creating a Java project with a package and a class with a main method, copying the project, pasting it into the same workspace, and refactoring it's name.